# Использование всех шаблонов из стандартной папки templates в ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

Создал роль myrole. В папку templates положил файлы index.j2 и page1.j2. Таски

```
- name: Copy HomePage
  template: src=index.j2 dest="{{ destin_path }}/index.html" mode=0555
- name: Copy HomePage
  template: src=page1.j2 dest="{{ destin_path }}/page1.html" mode=0555
```

Успешно переносят шаблоны, меняют их и переименовывают. То есть ansible сам понимает что нужно лезть в папку ./myrole/templates. Но как можно сделать это одной командой? что-то вроде:

```
- name: Copy HomePage
  template: src=*.j2 dest="{{ destin_path }}/*.html" mode=0555
```

Comment: Определить [with_items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id15) и перечислить файлы, который должны быть обработаны.

Comment: Согласен, это может помочь. Но только в случае, если знаешь какие файлы должны быть обработаны. Хотелось бы более универсальный скрипт чтобы не править его, если изменился состав переносимых файлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо [with_items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id15) можно использовать [with_fileglob](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#id4) для указания шаблонов поиска файлов:

```
- template:
    src :  {{ item }}
    dest: {{ item }}
    with_fileglob: '../templates/*'
```

---

> When using a relative path with with_fileglob in a role, Ansible
>   resolves the path relative to the roles//files directory.

Из-за этого в примере указан относительный путь до каталога `templates`. Ознакомьтесь с информацией по прикрепленной ссылке.

---

[Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#loops)